# Vue3 child components not rendering when using vue.esm.bundler

Tags: vuejs3

I have markup with multiple components in it like so:

```
<div class="root">
 <title></title>
 <child></child>
</div>
```

If this is child:

```
<template>
    <h1>CHILD</h1>
    <sub-child></sub-child>
</template>

<script>
import subChild from "./subChild.vue";

export default {
    name: 'Test',
    components: {subChild}
};
```

and this is the sub-child:

```
<template>
    <div class="subChild">
        <h1>SUB CHILD</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'subChild'
};
</script>
```

The page will render only the child template, it will not render the sub-child - so the markup ends up looking like this: (let's pretend `title` returns the H3)

```
<div class="root">
    <h3>Child and sub-child:</h3>
    <div class="subChild">
      <h1>CHILD</h1>
      <sub-child></sub-child>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the webpack config I've used this:

```
vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
```

as it will consume multiple components inside of .root (as shown in first snippet):

```
  createApp({
    components: {
        ...components
    }
    })
  .mount('.root');
```

where `components` contains the imported title, child and subchild components.

It's a lot of example code, but basically the createApp only goes one component deep.
Is there a way to recursively instantiate components or maybe this is a drawback to using vue.esm-bundler.js?